# Fortran 90 runtime error:end of file

Tags: fortran, runtime-error, fortran90

I'm sorry if this has been asked before, but I couldn't find an answer that seemed to work for me. I'm working with an old program, but have made a few modifications to it.

I can include the whole 2500 line program, but it seems like that is a lot.

I've successfully compiled the a program, but it fails when I try and run it. I'm getting a "Fortran runtime error: End of file" at the line which reads the .dat file. I've tried to compile a test segment, using the same .dat file and same variables. It results in the same problem.

```
PROGRAM OPEN
INTEGER (KIND=1), PARAMETER :: dy=3 ! number of income states 
INTEGER (KIND=2) :: OpenStatus
REAL, DIMENSION(dy) :: grid,wt
OPEN(1,file='cygdrive/user/mk.dat',status='old',form='formatted',IOSTAT=OpenStatus)

READ (1,*) grid, wt
IF(OpenStatus>0) STOP 'cannot open mk.dat'
CLOSE(1)

PRINT*, grid(1)
END PROGRAM
```

The data file referenced is:

> -1.7320508e+000
>
> 0.0000000e+000
>
> 1.7320508e+000
>
> 4.1777138e-001
>
> 1.6710855e+000
>
> 4.1777138e-001

Where each of these numbers is on its own line and preceeded by a space

This generates the same end of file runtime error. I'd really appreciate any help here.

I should add that I compiled with gfortran.

EDIT:

As per High Performance Mark's suggestion below, I've modified it to include an inquire test.

```
PROGRAM TEST
CHARACTER :: fnm, seq, fort
Logical :: lex
INTEGER (KIND=1), PARAMETER :: dy=3 ! number of income states 
INTEGER (KIND=2) :: j,j0,j1,j2,j4,j5,j6,j7,k,jjj,jj,dyy,OpenStatus
REAL, DIMENSION(dy) :: grid,wt
OPEN(1,file='cygdrive/user/mk.dat',status='old',form='formatted',IOSTAT=OpenStatus)
INQUIRE (1, EXIST=lex, NAME=fnm, SEQUENTIAL=seq, FORMATTED=fort)
PRINT*, 'Exists=',lex, ' Name=',fnm, ' Sequential=', seq, 'Formatted=', fort
READ (1,*) grid, wt
IF(OpenStatus>0) STOP 'cannot open mk.dat'
CLOSE(1)
PRINT*, grid(1)
END PROGRAM
```

The results of the inquire statement are:
 Exists= T  Name= Sequential=U   Formatted=U

My understanding is that the File is found (i.e. exists is returned as true), is un-named and the format and sequential access are returned as unknown (as is direct which I included later). I've also checked the delimiter and padding which are coming back as unknown.

My beginner intuition is telling me that I should try and create a new data file by writing to it with a fortran program and that should solve the problem? Is that correct? If so is there a fundamental misunderstanding at play here i.e. is this a problem with data files from other sources?

Thanks for all your patience.

Comment: Whaddya mean you get a run-time error at line 251 (don't tell us which is line 251, it's much more fun trying to figure that out) *which calls the .dat file* ?.  If you mean the `open` statement, test `iostat` immediately for success or otherwise. Right now your code ignores the error code and goes ahead and tries to read a couple of values, then tests the error code.  And are you sure the file is where the program is looking for it ? If you are sure, use the `inquire` statement to gather confirmation.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry that the original post lacked clarity. I hope I've fixed that now. It was in fact the read statement causing the error. I've incorporated the results of the inquire statement into the original post. I'd be grateful if you could shed some light. Cheers

Comment: The OpenStatus check should be placed immediately after the OPEN statement. Your inquire as it is now is useless! Use INQUIRE based on the filename, not on the unit number. If on unit number, it must be AFTER the check.

Comment: Now, it seems the data you print from the INQUIRE are just garbage.

Comment: BTW, what is the purpose of that `integer(kind=1)` and `integer(kind=2)` if you are just saving couple of bytes of memory or expecting better performance, then forget it. It may be even slower. Just use default integer.

Comment: Under keep it simple rules for personal use code I wouldn't use `IOSTAT` at all here. Take that out of your open statement and you will get a clear system error in the event the file is not found.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've fixed this problem-the program was looking for it in a different place, I've now corrected that.

Comment: It is interesting i think to point out `INQUIRE(unit=n,exists=` will as near as I can tell *always* return `true` indicating the *unit* exists, which is *always* the case regardless of whether the unit is attached to an open/existing file.  ( it seems to only return false on an illegal unit number )

Comment: Now voting to close this question, OP's comments make clear that the program is not in error.  This question has no lasting value here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

(Answered in the comments. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> I've fixed this problem-the program was looking for it in a different place, I've now corrected that.